# symfony date calculation different with two different years

Tags: symfony, date, timezone

I have a date conversion problem in my application.

i use symfony 2.8 and my Timezone is "Europe / Paris".

When i submit my form with `08/05/2000`, it sends to symfony `"2000-05-07T22:00:00.000Z"`

Symfony norm the data adding two hours so i have `2000-05-08` in my database that is correct.

If i do the same with `08/05/1964`, symfony only add 1 hour and i have `2000-05-07` in my database that is wrong.

Is this a bug ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i think the problem is not in symfony but in the datepicker i use (angular md-datepicker)

Before 1976, summer date didn't exist so symfony is true only adding 1 hour